# Understanding notation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, notation

Let $n\ge 2$ and $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$ with $f(0)=0$ being a strict local maximum for the function $f$. Denote by
$$F=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^n : f(x)<0\rbrace \cup \{0\}$$
and let $F_1$ be the component of $F$ containing $0$.

First question: What is meant by "component of $F$"? I would say that $F_1\subset F$ where, if for example $f$ is negative for $x\in A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, it is $$F_1 = A\cup\{0\}.$$
I am not sure about that.

Hence it is said that, if $F_1$ is bounded, we can conclude that
$$ f(x) < f(0)=0 \quad \forall x\in F_1$$
and $$f(x) = f(0)=0 \quad\text{ for } x\in\partial(F_1).$$

I think that $f(x) < f(0)=0 \ \forall x\in F_1$ comes from the definition of $F$ and the fact that $F_1\subset F$ is a component. The condition $f(x) = f(0)=0$ for $x\in\partial(F_1)$ it is not clear (to me) instead.

Could anyone please help to understand that?

${\bf EDIT:}$ The question concerns the paper
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02571356

I am trying to understand why the assumptions of Theorem 2.22 imply what the authors state in (1.3) and the 2 subsequents in the introduction at page $1$.

Comment: If $\{0\}$ wasn't "added" to $F$, $F=f^{-1}([-\infty,0))$ would be the reciprocal image of an open set by a continuous function, therefore an open set itself which the union of disjoint open intervals, its "connected components" and $0$ would not be part of any of these. The fact to add $\{0\}$ to $F$ has the consequence that $0$ is in the adherence of one of these connected components.

Comment: @MatthewTowers I have edited the question about that.

Answer (score 1):

In this context component means [connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components). Since $0$ is the strict local maximum of the function $f^{-1}(0)$ is necessarily the boundary. To see this note that for a continuous function the inverse image of an open set is open so the preimage $f^{-1}((-\infty , 0))$ is open and all of its points are interior. Since the boundary points are not interior we have $\partial(F_1) \subset f^{-1}(0)$. This shows for $x \in \partial F_1$ we have $f(x)=f(0)=0$.

Comment: CyclotomicField, thank you for the answer. Could you please explain why since 0
 is the strict local maximum of the function, hence $f^{-1}(0)$ is necessarily the boundary? Also, how we can deduce that $f(x)=f(0)=0 $ for $x\in\partial F_1$?

Comment: @Physicsuser I have added more detail as to why the boundary must be in $f^{-1}(0)$.